# Signed Application blocked by Java security settings

Tags: java, security, execution, signed, blocked

i have an applet prided by jnlp
this applet is thawte signed. so its a trusted app.

this morning a client call me beacause he can't launch my app.

indeed on his desktop the user have a strange warning screen :

[image: first warning]

[image: second warning]

after turning around for a moment i trow an eye on java security advanced setings.

we had lost an half working day to find a clue in our app or in the builsd process, but in fact the problem was a missconfiguration on the user desktop.

so because this king of advert is not showed on oracle docs and anywehe i search before, and because it could cause some trouble with users, time waste for dev team, and money lost at the end, i give you a solution for quick fix.

look the answer to know what to do.

Comment: You should post an answer instead of writing the answer into the question part

Comment: @Marcelo Funnily, the OP was already solved in the first revision, not an edit

Comment: @Marcelo why off topic ? it's an real issue. we had waste time on it because off the user destktop config. i just want to share this experiance because this warn is not referenced. and i think it could help, don't you ?

Comment: @DanielAlder Thank for embding images. i've fail to do that the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: the check boxes must be like this]

in java config security advanced
scroll until user evironment security
and be shure :

user can allow special authorisations to signed content is check

display sandbox warning is check

not to ask for client certificate when none exists or that one is check

Warn mismatch site certificate and hostname is check

and signed app with all-permission launch again